# Open the same form more than once

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Is it possible to open a form more than once?

button1
form2.show

Press button1
form2 opens up

press button1 again
another form2 opens up next to the old form2

If possible, can a button on Form1 kill all Form2 windows open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's possible. Just dim two instances of the same form.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private m_WindowList As New List(Of Form2)

    Private Sub OpenWindowButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OpenWindowButton.Click
        OpenWindow()
    End Sub

    Private Sub CloseWindowsButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CloseWindowsButton.Click
        CloseWindows()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenWindowsButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OpenWindowsButton.Click
        Dim WindowCount As Int32
        If Int32.TryParse(WindowCountTextBox.Text, WindowCount) Then
            OpenWindows(WindowCount)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenWindow()
        Dim NewWindow As New Form2
        m_WindowList.Add(NewWindow)
        NewWindow.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenWindows(ByVal Count As Int32)
        For i = 1 To Count
            OpenWindow()
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub CloseWindows()
        For Each Window In m_WindowList
            Window.Close()
            Window.Dispose()
        Next
        m_WindowList.Clear()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
m_WindowList.Add(NewWindow)
problem with that line

Comment: Ah, sorry, add New to the declaration of m_WindowList. I've fixed it in the answer above.

Comment: Heh, don't ask me why I did this, but I cleaned it up and added the additional multi-open capability you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim MyNewForm2 = New Form2
MyNewForm2.Show
```

Comment: just out of curiosity. is there a way to make one button1 to open up how ever many windows as a number in a textbox describs? and also to close all form2 disabling what ever there working on as well?

Comment: @SirAudens, there are several ways to achieve it, one simple way would be to keep a reference to all the new windows in a local array, then at the second button click close/kill them all.

Comment: BTW, please don't forget to mark the post as answer if that solved your issue.

Comment: TY its what i was looking for. i wish i could have more then 1 accepted answers becuz u an tel help me. but sadly Tel had more of the info i needed